# How to prolong do... while loop after Exception catch

Tags: java, loops, exception, try-catch, do-while

I am completly new to programming and I've faced a problem, where I can't return to my main do while loop when I catch InputMismatchException. I searched Google and I can't find and fully understand solutions which are given by Users.

My goal is to eliminate possibility for Users to input any characters which could couse application to terminate. That's why I surrounded almost all code with try/catch.

I tried to put more loops to my code and it all ends in 2 ways:

1. My loop never finishes after reaching catch statement.
2. I am put back to console and nothing happens (I can still type in there).

Could someone explain my how to reach my goal? I've also tried hasNextInt hoping it will ask me again to input proper value but it does not. What am I doing wrong? I debugged application and what I can see is that procedure is skipped from while to the end of my code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("\nChoose mode: ");

int userInput = 0;

do {
    do {
        try {
            userInput = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (userInput) {
                case 1:
                    Mode_1.multiplyTwoInteger();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Mode_2.multiplyTwoSpecifiedValues();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\nYou quit application. Goodbye :)");
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.print("Not found! Choose again game mode: ");
            }
        } catch (Exception InputMismatchException) {
            System.out.print("Wrong input!\nChoose again:");
        }
    } while (userInput <= 0 || userInput > 3);
} while (userInput != 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this exception, your console has this exception present and **`nextInt()`** will read it as a bad format and will give **InputMismatchException**.

try re-intializing the **scanner** object in catch block like **scanner=new Scanner(System.in);** or you can do it reading a bad input **scanner.nextLine()**.

Try changing your code to match as below:

```
try {
                    userInput = scanner.nextInt();
                    switch (userInput) {
                        case 1:
                            Mode_1.multiplyTwoInteger();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Mode_2.multiplyTwoSpecifiedValues();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("\nYou quit application. Goodbye :)");
                            return;
                        default:
                            System.out.print("Not found! Choose again game mode: ");
                    }
                } catch (Exception InputMismatchException) {
                    scanner=new Scanner(System.in); // Reinitiate the scanner object or use scanner.nextLine() to read bad input.
                    System.out.print("Wrong input!\nChoose again:");
                }
```

Comment: That is new knowledge to me. I didn't know it works this way. Thank you very much for you solution.